# Keystroke to press BasicButton in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to press a button on a from that I built using keystrokes.

- If I use the mouse and click on the button, no problem at all, all works.
- I have tried to use the & in text box to provide a short whilst pressing ALT. No joy

I do not know much about .NET, however about a day of look I can say it is not so straight forward.

I would like to add a shortcut, e.g. Press B and it works as if I were press the button, in this case: BasicButton1_Click

Here is all the code I have at present.

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub MainForm_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        If e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
            BasicButton1.PerformClick()
        End If
    End Sub
    '*******************************************************************************
    '* Stop polling when the form is not visible in order to reduce communications
    '* Copy this section of code to every new form created
    '*******************************************************************************
    Private Sub Form_VisibleChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.VisibleChanged
        AdvancedHMIDrivers.Utilities.StopComsOnHidden(components, Me)
    End Sub

    '**************************************
    '* Filling the form with a gradient
    '**************************************
    'Private Sub MainForm_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    'Dim rect As New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Height)
    'Dim gradientBrush As New Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Height), System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(180, 100, 200), System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(110, 200, 255))
    'e.Graphics.FillRectangle(gradientBrush, rect)
    'End Sub

    Private Sub BasicButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BasicButton1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub BasicButton7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BasicButton7.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub BasicButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BasicButton2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub BasicButton5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BasicButton5.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub BasicButton3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BasicButton3.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Place an `&` in the Button.Text before the character you want to act as the key trigger.

For example, if the button text is "Click Me!", and you want <kbd>Alt-M</kbd> to trigger the button, then set the Button.Text to `Click &Me!`.

That's it.  Windows/.NET will take care of the rest.

Comment: Hello, I did that.. Not joy.I stated above, sorry if it was not clear.